# Using styled-components with imported CSS files from a node_module

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components in a React project. So far it has been working fine, but now I want to use the [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) package, which requires its styles to be imported the following way:

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

However, importing the file causes an error that says "`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`". I know I could fix this by creating a handler for .css files, but I thought I could avoid that by using Styled Components.

My question is, **is there a way to handle these type of imports with styled components?** I've been loooking online for hours and can't seem to find a way.

Comment: `css-loader` ??

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just forking the project and changing it to use styled-components instead of needing to import the styles.